# Why using Java threads is not much faster?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following program to remove even numbers from a string vector, when the vector size grows larger, it might take a long time, so I thought of threads, but using 10 threads is not faster then one thread, my PC has 6 cores and 12 threads, why ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test_Threads
{
  static boolean Use_Threads_To_Remove_Duplicates(Vector<String> Good_Email_Address_Vector,Vector<String> To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector)
  {
    boolean Removed_Duplicates=false;
    int Threads_Count=10,Delay=5,Average_Size_For_Each_Thread=Good_Email_Address_Vector.size()/Threads_Count;

    Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread RDFVT[]=new Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread[Threads_Count];
    Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread.To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector=To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector;
    for (int i=0;i<Threads_Count;i++)
    {
      Vector<String> Target_Vector=new Vector<String>();
      if (i<Threads_Count-1) for (int j=i*Average_Size_For_Each_Thread;j<(i+1)*Average_Size_For_Each_Thread;j++) Target_Vector.add(Good_Email_Address_Vector.elementAt(j));
      else for (int j=i*Average_Size_For_Each_Thread;j<Good_Email_Address_Vector.size();j++) Target_Vector.add(Good_Email_Address_Vector.elementAt(j));
      RDFVT[i]=new Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread(Target_Vector,Delay);
    }

    try { for (int i=0;i<Threads_Count;i++) RDFVT[i].Remover_Thread.join(); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }                                                   // Wait for all threads to finish

    for (int i=0;i<Threads_Count;i++) if (RDFVT[i].Changed) Removed_Duplicates=true;

    if (Removed_Duplicates)                                                                        // Collect results
    {
      Good_Email_Address_Vector.clear();
      for (int i=0;i<Threads_Count;i++) Good_Email_Address_Vector.addAll(RDFVT[i].Target_Vector);
    }

    return Removed_Duplicates;
  }

  public static void out(String message) { System.out.print(message); }
  public static void Out(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

    Vector<String> Good_Email_Address_Vector=new Vector<String>(),To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector=new Vector<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) Good_Email_Address_Vector.add(i+"");
    Out(Good_Email_Address_Vector.toString());
    for (int i=0;i<1500000;i++) To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector.add(i*2+"");
    Out("=============================");

    Use_Threads_To_Remove_Duplicates(Good_Email_Address_Vector,To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector);  // [ Approach 1 : Use 10 threads ] 
//    Good_Email_Address_Vector.removeAll(To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector);                       // [ Approach 2 : just one thread ]
    Out(Good_Email_Address_Vector.toString());

    long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Out("Time taken for execution is " + (end - start));
  }
}

class Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread
{
  static Vector<String> To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector;
  Vector<String> Target_Vector;
  Thread Remover_Thread;
  boolean Changed=false;

  public Remove_Duplicate_From_Vector_Thread(final Vector<String> Target_Vector,final int Delay)
  {
    this.Target_Vector=Target_Vector;

    Remover_Thread=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(Delay);
          Changed=Target_Vector.removeAll(To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally { }
      }
    });
    Remover_Thread.start();
  }
}
```

In my program you can try "[ Approach 1 : Use 10 threads ]" or "[ Approach 2 : just one thread ]" there isn't much difference speed wise, I expext it to be several times faster, why ?

Comment: Threads has a cost, and lock contention has a huge cost.

Comment: How large was the initial Vector?

Comment: You should follow conventions for the language you are writing; don't make up your own. This code is hard to read because it uses unconventional capitalization and underscores.

Comment: I agree with @erickson.  And the one-liner if / for combos are making my eyes hurt.

Comment: Why is there a call to `sleep()` in each thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Vector Synchronization Creates Contention

You've split up the vector to be modified, which avoids a *some* contention. But multiple threads are accessing a the `static Vector To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector`, so much  contention still remains (all `Vector` methods are synchronized).

Use an unsynchronized data structure for the shared, read-only information so that there is no contention between threads. On my machine, running your test with `ArrayList` in place of `Vector` cut the execution time in half.

Even without contention, thread-safe structures are slower, so don't use them when only a single thread has access to an object. Additionally, `Vector` is largely obsolete by Java 5. Avoid it unless you have to inter-operate with a legacy API you can't alter.

### Choose a Suitable Data Structure

A list data structure is going to provide poor performance for this task. Since email addresses are likely to be unique, a set should be a suitable replace, and will `removeAll()` much faster on large sets. Using `HashSet` in place of the original `Vector` cut execution time on my (8 core) machine from *over 5 seconds to around 3 milliseconds.* Roughly half of this improvement is due to using the right data structure for the job.

### Concurrent Structures Are a Bad Fit

Using a concurrent concurrent data structure is relatively slow, and doesn't simplify the code, so I don't recommend it.

Using a more up-to-date concurrent data structure is much faster than contending for a `Vector`, but the concurrency overhead of these data structures is still much higher than  single-threaded structures. For example, running the original code on my machine took more than five seconds, while a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` took half a second, and a `ConcurrentHashMap` took one eighth of a second. But remember, when each thread had its own `HashSet` to update, the total time was just 3 milliseconds.

Even when all threads are updating a single concurrent data structure, the code needed to partition the workload is very similar to that used to create a separate `Vector` for each thread in the original code. From a readability and maintenance standpoint, all of these solutions have equivalent complexity.

If you had a situation where "bad" email addresses were being added to the set asynchronously, and you wanted readers of the "good" list to see those updates auto-magically, a concurrent set would be a good choice. But, with the current design of the API, where consumers of the "good" list explicitly call a blocking filter method to update the list, a concurrent data structure may be the wrong choice.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is that your threads are all trying to access a single vector calling synchronized methods.  The `synchronized` modifier on those methods *ensures* that only one thread can be executing any of the methods on that object at any given time.  So a significant part of the parallel part of the computation involves waiting for other threads.

The other problem is that for an `O(N)` input list, you have an `O(N)` setup ... population of the Target_Vector objects ... that is done in one thread.  Plus the overheads of thread creation.

All of this adds up to not much speedup.

---

You should get a significant speedup (with multiple threads) if you used a single `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a single `Good_Email_Address_Vector` object that gets split into multiple `Target_Vector` objects:

- the remove operation is `O(1)` not `O(n)`,
- reduced copying,
- the data structure provides better multi-threaded performance due to better handling of contention, and
- you don't need to jump through hoops to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`.

In addition, the `To_Be_Removed_Email_Address_Vector` object should be replaced with an unsynchronized `List`, and `List.sublist(...)` should be used to create views that can be passed to the threads.

---

In short, you are better of throwing away your current code and starting again.  And **please** use sensible identifier names that follow the Java coding conventions, and 
wrap your code at line ~80 so that people can read it!

Comment: Or `Set<String> set = Collections.setFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>()`

Comment: They aren't updating the same vector; every thread has it's own vector for modification.

Comment: @erikson - but the threads are all using a single Vector to find the addresses to be removed.

Comment: Yes, my comment applied to your original answer, which said that a single collection was updated by multiple threads.

Comment: @erikson - so your comment is no longer relevant now.  Correct?

Comment: No, I think that subsequent comments have given it continued relevance. Your answer is unclear; it sounds like you are suggesting that `Good_Email_Address_Vector` should be a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

All your threads are working on the same vector.  Your access to the vector is serialized (i.e. only one thread can access it at a time) so using multiple threads is likely to be the same speed at best, but more likely to be much slower.

Multiple threads work much faster when you have independent tasks to perform.

In this case, the fastest option is likely to be to create a new List which contains all the elements you want to retain and replacing the original, **in one thread**.  This will be fastest than using a concurrent collection with multiple threads.

---

For comparison, this is what you can do with one thread.  As the collection is fairly small, the JVM doesn't warmup in just one run, so there are multiple dummy runs which are not printed.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
    for (int n = -50; n < 5; n++) {
        List<String> allIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) allIds.add(String.valueOf(i));

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        List<String> oddIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String id : allIds) {
            if ((id.charAt(id.length()-1) % 2) != 0)
                oddIds.add(id);
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        if (n >= 0)
            System.out.println("Time taken to filter " + allIds.size() + " entries was " + time / 1000 + " micro-seconds");
    }
}
```

prints

```
Time taken to filter 1000 entries was 136 micro-seconds
Time taken to filter 1000 entries was 141 micro-seconds
Time taken to filter 1000 entries was 136 micro-seconds
Time taken to filter 1000 entries was 137 micro-seconds
Time taken to filter 1000 entries was 138 micro-seconds
```